# Java game development. Making the monster move random in a maze

Tags: java, maze, pacman

I was writing a pacman styled game in which the monsters are assumed to move in a random direction in the maze. But I can't figure it out how to make them adapt the right direction they want. I was using some constants for the directions.

```
public class Monster extends GObject {

    private final int DIRECTION_UP = 0;
    private final int DIRECTION_DOWN = 1;
    private final int DIRECTION_LEFT = 2;
    private final int DIRECTION_RIGHT = 3;

    private int DIRECTION = 2;

    private float speed = 0.06f;

    public Monster(float x, float y){
        super(Treasure.MONSTER_LEFT);
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
        DIRECTION = random(3);
    }

    public void update(long elapsedTime){
        setVelocityX(0);
        setVelocityY(0);
        switch (DIRECTION){
            case DIRECTION_UP :
                setVelocityY(-speed);
                setImage(Treasure.MONSTER_UP);
                break;
            case DIRECTION_DOWN :
                setVelocityY(speed);
                setImage(Treasure.MONSTER_DOWN);
                break;
            case DIRECTION_LEFT :
                setVelocityX(-speed);
                setImage(Treasure.MONSTER_LEFT);
                break;
            case DIRECTION_RIGHT :
                setVelocityX(speed);
                setImage(Treasure.MONSTER_RIGHT);
                break;
        }
        changeDirection();
    }

    private int random(int x){
        return (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (x+1));
    }

    public void collision(GObject other){
        if (other instanceof Wall){
            switch (DIRECTION){
                case DIRECTION_UP :
                    setY(other.getY()+other.getHeight());
                    break;
                case DIRECTION_DOWN :
                    setY(other.getY()-getHeight());
                    break;
                case DIRECTION_LEFT :
                    setX(other.getX()+other.getWidth());
                    break;
                case DIRECTION_RIGHT :
                    setX(other.getX()-getWidth());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the changeDirection() method I've using.

```
private void changeDirection(){
    int random = random(1);
    boolean opposite = (random==1);
    int dir = DIRECTION;
    switch (Explorer.DIRECTION){
        case DIRECTION_UP :
            if (opposite){
                dir = DIRECTION_DOWN;
            } else {
                dir = DIRECTION_UP;
            }
            break;
        case DIRECTION_DOWN :
            if (opposite){
                dir = DIRECTION_UP;
            } else {
                dir = DIRECTION_DOWN;
            }
            break;
        case DIRECTION_LEFT :
            if (opposite){
                dir = DIRECTION_RIGHT;
            } else {
                dir = DIRECTION_LEFT;
            }
            break;
        case DIRECTION_RIGHT :
            if (opposite){
                dir = DIRECTION_LEFT;
            } else {
                dir = DIRECTION_RIGHT;
            }
            break;
    }
    switch (dir){
        case DIRECTION_UP :
            if (Map.isObjectCollisionFree(getX(), getY()-1, true, this)){
                DIRECTION = dir;
            }
            break;
        case DIRECTION_DOWN :
            if (Map.isObjectCollisionFree(getX(), getY()+1, true, this)){
                DIRECTION = dir;
            }
            break;
        case DIRECTION_LEFT :
            if (Map.isObjectCollisionFree(getX()-1, getY(), true, this)){
                DIRECTION = dir;
            }
            break;
        case DIRECTION_RIGHT :
            if (Map.isObjectCollisionFree(getX()+1, getY(), true, this)){
                DIRECTION = dir;
            }
    }
}
```

Could anybody help me with how to make the monster move random in the maze...

The current issue I'm facing is that the monsters are not moving.. they are jumping in the game. If they are outside the view, they never comes back.. Monitoring them said me that their co-ordinates reach as much as -12000 and stops there. This is how I check for walls.

```
if (Map.isObjectCollisionFree(<x-pos>, <y-pos>, <solid-state>, <object>))
```

and this has worked for the player. In the collision method, I'm aligning the monster with the grid of the map.

EDIT : changed the changeDirection() method

```
    private void changeDirection(){     
        DIRECTION = random(3);
}

the update() method

    public void update(long elapsedTime){
    if (MapView.isVisible(this)){
        if ((getX()%Map.TILE_SIZE==0) && (getY()%Map.TILE_SIZE==0)){
            changeDirection();
        }
        setVelocityX(0);
        setVelocityY(0);
        switch (DIRECTION){
            case DIRECTION_UP :
                setVelocityY(-speed);
                setImage(Treasure.MONSTER_UP);
                break;
            case DIRECTION_DOWN :
                setVelocityY(speed);
                setImage(Treasure.MONSTER_DOWN);
                break;
            case DIRECTION_LEFT :
                setVelocityX(-speed);
                setImage(Treasure.MONSTER_LEFT);
                break;
            case DIRECTION_RIGHT :
                setVelocityX(speed);
                setImage(Treasure.MONSTER_RIGHT);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a real question.  You can't just dump all your code and say "please help me".

Comment: Please describe the issue you are currently having.

Comment: Your problem is probably in the code that changes the monster's location, which you didn't even show.

Comment: @Brilliand I am using a game engine which determines the co-ordinates automatically basing on the velocities. The objects are moved automatically and any collisions are reported to the collision method where I am aligning the object to the grid by switching the direction.

Comment: Why do you make it go in opposite direction if random is 1? Don't you want to use random for direction? What is `Explorer.DIRECTION`??

Comment: When the monster jumps on the map, where does it jump to?  Does it always jump to another side of an adjacent wall?

Comment: @Shredder Explorer.DIRECTION is the current direction of the explorer. I am using opposite to make a chance of left or right to the current direction.

Comment: @Brilliand Yeah, it is jumping to the other side. But once it is outside the view i.e, the visible area, it dis-appears and it's coordinates decrease

Comment: Then I think it's the `collision()` method doing the jumping - the monsters might be managing to collide with walls that they aren't moving in the direction of.

Comment: Specifically, `changeDirection()` changes which way the monster thinks it's going, but not the direction it's really moving in.  Then there's a collision, and the monster jumps to the side of the wall that it would be on if it was moving in the direction that it thinks it's moving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code you provided, there will be periods where the monster is moving in one direction, but thinks that it's moving in another (because `changeDirection()` changes the internal direction value, but not the monster's velocity).  Then when the monster crashes into a wall while thinking that it's moving in a different direction entirely, it jumps to the side of the wall that it would be on if it were moving in the direction that it thinks it's moving... and proceeds on its merry way in the direction that it was really moving in, untill the next call to `update()`.

To fix this, move the call to `changeDirection()` from the end of `update()` to the beginning.  Actually, I'd suggest moving all of the code in `update()` to the end of `changeDirection()`, but it'll work either way.

Comment: Because the other guy deleted his answer: I suggest replacing the entire first `switch` statement in `changeDirection()` with `dir = random(3);`.  That will fix the problem of the monsters never turning left or right.

Comment: Then the problem arises again, the monsters arent coming out of the pit

Comment: Reducing your `changeDirection()` method to `DIRECTION = random(3);` might be overzealous - it will cause monsters to occasionally stop moving and stick their face against a wall.  The code to avoid pointing a monster into a wall was a good thing.